# Fetching text field from the node

Tags: 7, javascript

I am working on **flex slider module** and I want to add **one button** in caption so for that I have added **one field** in content type with `Machine name: field_image_url` and `Field Type: text`.

Now I am changing in **core file** of the module to fetch that `URL` into the **front end**.For that code is below:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * @file
     * Default output for a Flex Slider node.
    */
    ?>
    <div class="flex-nav-container">
      <div class="flexslider-content flexslider clearfix" id="flexslider-<?php print $id; ?>">
        <ul class="slides">
        <?php foreach($items as $item) : ?>
          <li><?php print render($item); ?>
            <?php if(!empty($item['#item']['title']) || !empty($item['#item']['alt'])) : ?>
             <div class="flex-caption">
             <h3><?php print $item['#item']['alt'];?></h3>
             <p><?php print $item['#item']['title']; ?></p>
             <?php if(isset($node->field_image_url)): ?>
                <a href="<?php print render ($node->$field_image_url); ?>" class="btn btn-theme">Learn More</a>
             <?php endif; ?>
             </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I know I am making **some mistake** as I am very **new to drupal development**.

```
     <?php if(isset($node->field_image_url)): ?>
        <a href="<?php print render ($node->$field_image_url); ?>" class="btn btn-theme">Learn More</a>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Above code is for fetching URL.It is **not** giving me **any error**, but it is also not showing me the button.I have already entered URL for one slide.

Where am I lacking ?

**Edited** :

I want to also mention that `Slider` is on **front page** and there is an **article content** just below to the slider.

I have given **node path** to the front page from the Configuration to show it on **front page**.

So now, If I do

```
     <?php 
        if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
          // Get the nid
          $nid = arg(1);
          // Load the node if you need to
          $node = node_load($nid); print_r($node);
        }
     ?>
```

It is giving me the `node ID` of the **article**.I want the `node ID` of the **slider Image** so that I can pull out the `image URL field` that I have added to the **Slider Image Content type**.

**EDITED**:

```
    <?php
        //this code will load all nodes from your content type and then print them
        $node_type = "slider_image"; 
        $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = '%s' ", $node_type);
        $nodes = array();
        while ($obj = db_fetch_object ($result)) {
          $node = node_load($obj->nid);
          echo $node->field_image_url['und'][0]['value'];
          echo '<br>';
          $nodes[] = node_load($obj->nid);
        }
    ?>
```

I have tried above code but it is giving me an error : 
`Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be of the type array, string given, called in path to modules\modules\flexslider\theme\flexslider-container.tpl.php on line 19 and defined in db_query() (line 2345 of path to site\includes\database\database.inc).`

So to resolve above error, I tried following code with help of [`this`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7):

`$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = ':type' ", array(':type' => $node_type));`

But above code also gives me error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined function db_fetch_object() in path to module\modules\flexslider\theme\flexslider-container.tpl.php on line 21`

Answer (score 1):

In general to get the value of field if the entity type is a node

```
$node = node_load($nid);
echo $node->field_image_url['und'][0]['value'];
```

or try to print the $node to figure out how to get it

```
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($node); var_dump($node->field_image_url); die;
```

in your situation try the next to figure out what is happen there

```
<?php
$node_type = "slider_image";
$sql = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = $node_type");
$results = db_query($sql);
foreach($results as $row){
   $node = node_load($row->nid);
   echo $node->field_image_url['und'][0]['value'];
   echo '<br>';  
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time.`echo $node->field_image_url['und'][0]['value'];` <-- this code give me an error and `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($node); var_dump($node->field_image_url); die;` <-- this code gives me article's node ID which is just below to the slider.

Also want to mention that above given code in question is in to the module file not in to the theme file.

Comment: Actually I am not familiar about your module (flex slider module ) but I was talking in general, so you should be sure you load the correct node, and be sure this node type has this field, and then my code will work

Comment: In general, it works nice coz I have used same code in `template.php` for another field that I have added to the `Article` content type.I dont know the reason,but it only gets node ID of the article which is below the slider.Do you know anything that can give all the node ID of the current page ?

Comment: which content type you use to add the "field_image_url" field ??

Comment: I have made new content type `Slider Image` and `field_image_url`is having **TEXT** as ``field type`.

Comment: I added some code on my answer you can use it to figure out what is happen there, this code will load all node from your content type and then print them

Comment: Okay .. Let me try this code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19916/discussion-between-mohammad-alabed-and-twix).

Comment: See my edited part.

Comment: I have also tried `field_get_items` without any success.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [field_get_items](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) or if you are using wonderful [entity api module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)  you can use [entity_metadata_wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers). Using ['und'][0]['value'] is not a best way to get field values in drupal.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use KPR function that comes with devel module. Once you enable the module you could add kpr($fields) function and it show you the structure of data returned by drupal. In general it should be something like $fields->field_image_url['und'][0]['value'];